# Realm.io complete callback

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm to save my data. I don't find any way to get a complete or fail callback when it comes to writes to the database?

Is there any way to know when realm is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm-Java is not asynchronous as far as I can tell. The classic way to [write data](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#writes) is by using a write transaction and creating/modifying an object during that transaction:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
User user = realm.createObject(User.class); // Create a new object
user.setName("John");
user.setEmail("john@corporation.com");
realm.commitTransaction();
```

From the [Realm-Java API](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/) for `commitTransaction`:

> All changes since beginTransaction() are persisted to disk and the Realm reverts back to being read-only. An event is sent to notify all other realm instances that a change has occurred. When the event is received, the other Realms will get their objects and RealmResults updated to reflect the changes from this commit.

I believe the commit is atomic, and simply succeeds or fails. If it fails, you'll get an exception. As soon as the code returns, the data has been saved.

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure about this.